# How to do test after connection with mongoose to atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js, mongodb-atlas

I want to test create user, so after connection to the DB I want to delete all the users that I tested and after it, I want to create new for the test.(Mocha)
**test_helper.js**

```
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
mongoose.connection
    .once('open', () => {
        console.log("connected")
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
        console.warn('Warning', error)
    });

beforeEach((done) => {
    mongoose.connection.collections.users.drop(() => {
        done();
    }
    )
})
```

**create_test.js**

```
describe('Creating', () => {
    it('saves a user', () => {
        const testUser = new User({ name: 'Test' });
        testUser.save();
    });
});
```

I am getting the next error
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

what do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some topics before my answer:

**Asynchronous coding:**
If you don't know/ are sure how it works, I recommend you to stop and learn about it: callback,Promises, async / await.

**Testing:**
Basically the flow is : create some scenario and assert some case, for example the attached code. I created a user and tested if it really work.

**Testing Asynchronous code:** after you read about callback function you can understand that done() is a callback function that permit finish the current async. function and pass to the next async. function.

`testUser.save()` returns a Promise and you aren't handling it.

```
...
testUser.save().then(()=>{
assert(testUser.isNew === false)
done();
} 
...
```

It should work, but if you want to test some scenarios one after other you should handle it.

```
describe('Creating', () => {
    it('some test', (done) => {
// some logic
done()
}
    it('another test', (done) => {
// some logic
done()
}
    });
});
```